# Cannot import class from Library.jar file after ProGuard Obfuscation

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation

I have build a .jar Library file. I can import it normally in my project but after Proguard Obfuscation, I could not call the class/function from that library anymore. My package and classes have been converted to a.class, b.class, c.class as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard renames classes.  When distributing a library, you need to configure ProGuard to not rename the API you need to be exposed.

You can add a rule like:

```
-keep public class * {
     public protected *;
}
```

This will stop renaming of all public & protected methods in all public classes.

Comment: You may also want to add flags like:

     -keepparameternames
     -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
     -keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                 SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

Comment: May I know where can I add this rule in ProGuard GUI? Thanks